# Cassandra and social "unfriend" / "unfollow"

Tags: cassandra, cql

### Intro

I'm getting to know Cassandra a bit more and creating a simple social network (similar to Instagram/Facebook).

The general idea is, you can follow/friend people and see their updates in a feed.
When launching an application, you should be able to scroll through the feed (updates sorted by time) and paginate it.

In my case I'm sticking with the **fan-out** approach - whenever an update is being published, it will be pushed to the feeds of friends/followers.

Here's what my schema looks like.

```
CREATE TABLE feed_by_time (
    user_id uuid,
    time timestamp,
    author_id uuid,
    post_id uuid,
    PRIMARY KEY  (user_id, time, author_id)
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (time DESC);
```

With this table, I should be able to get any users' feed easily and in sorted order, as well as paginate it further, and each users' feed will reside in its own partition, so I will not fetch from multiple nodes. I am a bit limited by the potential size of each partition, but let's assume it's not a problem right now.

### Problem

Now, the actual problem - how should unfollow/unfriend functionality be implemented? It assumes that all the posts of a specific "author" should disappear from your feed.

I know that with the `feed_by_time` table I will not be able to delete all the posts of a specific "author" so I can have another one like:

```
CREATE TABLE feed_by_author (
    user_id uuid,
    author_id uuid,
    post_id uuid,
    time timestamp,
    PRIMARY KEY ((user_id, author_id), post_id)
);
```

and write to them at the same time, when a new post is published.

When I unfollow someone, I can do something like

1. `SELECT * FROM feed_by_author WHERE user_id="user_id" AND author_id="unfriended_id"`
2. Extract `time` for query result entry and run A LOT of `DELETE` queries towards `feed_by_time`
3. Run one big `DELETE` to clean-up `feed_by_author` (in this case it will remove the entire partition)

My worry is mostly around the second point. I read that I should avoid such deletes since they are extremely costly.
So, should I be worried, and are there more efficient/correct ways of doing this?
Would having a `deleted` column, and setting it's value to 1 via `UPDATE` be more efficient?

### Follow-up

As a follow up to this question - say, I re-follow/re-friend someone. This will result in a lot of `INSERT` into the `feed_by_time` user-specific partition since we will be effectively merging the entire author feed into the users feed. The `time` value on each post can vary a lot, so we can be inserting it in the "middle" of the partition. Is it costly in terms of performance?

Thanks! :)

Answer (score -1):

you should have a table `friendships`

```
user_id
friend_id
```

and a table `posts`

```
post_id
user_id
post_text
date
```

to follow:

```
insert into friendships ( user_id, friend_id) values (whatevermyid, whateverfriendid)
```

when you want to get the feed of the user:

```
select post_id, post_text, date, friend_id from friendships f join posts p on f.friend_id=p.user_id and f.user_id=whatevermyid order by date desc
```

when you unfollow someone:

```
delete from friendships where friend_id=whateverfriendid and user_id=whatevermyid
```

which will actualy be one record

Comment: Unfortunately, there are no joins in Cassandra. Thanks for trying though, I do understand how to build this on MySQL :) The main question is mostly around the performance impact of the potential high-frequency deletes in Cassandra.

Comment: couldn't you use an ODBC driver just to make queries and join? if your tables won't be too large and not in clusters, otherwise it is not recommended, But from what I understand at least for the moment they will not be, so you can try using a free ODBC, there are some that will do the job pretty nice